# API для андроида или сервера

Tags: android

Уважаемые знатоки, кто нибудь сталкивался с такой ситуацией, где можно найти API 
 или такую базу данных наподобие vkmbot в телеграмме (или откуда шазам берет данные ), возможно такой вопрос будет актуален Буду благодарен если укажете ссылку, сам найти не смог

Comment: Неясно что именно вам нужно. Вообще абстрактные API открытые или вы имеете в виду какие-то узкоспециализированные? Что скрывается за теми названиями, что вы в вопросе упомянули?

Comment: Вопрос состоит в том, откуда шазам берет данные при запросе к примеру

Comment: Также если не трудно, хотя бы ссылочку на нужную информацию, Мне  интересен  пример получения музыки с сервера  то есть при запросе пользователя он смог найти любую песню исполнителя ?

Comment: Посмотрите тут https://rapidapi.com/blog/top-free-music-data-apis/